# PostgreSQL delete from parent table only

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have a table structure with partitioned tables, where a few child tables inherit from a common parent. How so I `DELETE` **only** from the parent table?

Long story short, I ended up with some data in the parent table, and this should've never happened but now I have to clean up the mess.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can specify that only parent table matters, simply by using keyword 'ONLY':

```
DELETE FROM ONLY parent_table_name;
```

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-delete.html

Comment: Glad to hear. By the way, please, remember not to loose these rows definitily before storing them in other place or migrating to the descending tables.